# Hibernate getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I'm having some trouble with an HQL query where I am using a result of sub query as DTO constructor parameter. Please see following example

```
select new com.bla.MyDTO(e.id, e.title, (select ... )) from com.bla.Entity1 e where ...
```

I am getting following exception from hibernate.

> **getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode!**

The exception is raised by ConstructorNode class line 133. I have checked the implementation of ConstructorNode and the method is deprecated and throws UnsupportedOperationException.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please note that I have also tried using new "java.util.ArrayList((select ...))" instead of "(select ...)" as constructor args and it gives me query compilation error.